# R: Looping a custom function over specific rows and columns

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I want to loop over a selection of columns and across all their rows and apply an If Else nested function in order to replace all the elements.

```
Table[c("Pb","Pc","Pd","Pe","Pf")] <-  lapply(Table[c("Pb","Pc","Pd","Pe","Pf")], function(x) {
                                       if (x <0.50) {round_any(x,0.05)}
                                  else if (x <1.00) {round_any(x,0.10)}
                                  else if (x <2.00) {round_any(x,0.25)}
                                  else if (x <5.00) {round_any(x,0.50)}
                                  else              {round_any(x,1)}
                                              })
```

The code runs but I am getting the following warning:
    `1: In if (x < 0.5) { ... :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`and the results are not exactly as I expected. Is there another way I can produce this output?

Comment: The columns have lenvgth greater than 1 and `if/else` works only on length 1.  You may need `ifelse`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I solved it based on your tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table[c("Pb","Pc","Pd","Pe","Pf")] <- lapply(Table[c("Pb","Pc","Pd","Pe","Pf")], function(x) {
                                       ifelse (x <0.50, round_any(x,0.05),
                                       ifelse (x <1.00, round_any(x,0.10),
                                       ifelse (x <2.00, round_any(x,0.25),
                                       ifelse (x <5.00, round_any(x,0.50), 
                                               round_any(x,1)))))})
```